# APDU Command VERIFY returns 6a88

Tags: java, apdu, verify

I have a FEITIAN BR301 reader and i am trying to run the VERIFY APDU command but the result is 6a88 (Referenced data not found).

My PIN is "012345" and based on some examples my command APDU is:

```
00 20 00 00 06 30 31 32 33 34 35
```

I hope the answer is 9000 but it is 6a88

This is the code:

```
String sendStr = "0020000006303132333435";

byte[] send = Utility.hexStrToBytes(sendStr);

byte[] recv = ftReader.readerXfr(0, send);

showLog("send response ---> "+Utility.bytes2HexStr(recv));
```

The result is `send response ---> 6a88`

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the identifier of the PIN to verify in P2. The id is typically in the range of 0x01..0x1f. The most significant bit of P2 for this command specifies whether to search for the PIN in the MF (0) or in the current DF (1).

Comment: While P2=0 also may work (if the card only has one PIN or the one to use is known implicitly), instead giving a non-zero PIN id is much more likely to succeed.